# Velocity change of objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Is it possible for small object (small mass, let's say bullet) to hit large object (big mass, let's say rock) and still move forward (or stop) instead of being reflected (let's say objects don't crush and collision takes place in one dimension)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, definitely. One example is an inelastic collision, where both masses will have the same velocity after colliding. In this case, let's say a bullet of mass $m$ and speed $v_0$ hits a stationary rock of mass $M$ and they stick together and move with a final speed $v$. Intuitively, you can already tell that their velocity must be in the same direction as the bullet's initial velocity. But let's make it explicit:
From conservation of momentum, we have that
$$mv_0=Mv+mv$$
$$mv_0=(M+m)v$$
Since mass must always be positive, $v$ must have the same sign as $v_0$, which means that the bullet moves in the same direction as before-keeps moving forward (although at a slower speed)-and is not 'reflected' by the rock.

EDIT (To respond to additional question). Under what conditions does this happen? Essentially, the bullet would have to stick 'into' the rock.

Comment: Come to think of that when I shoot to rock from certain distance the bigger the force I use to fire bullet the greater is distance the bullet gets reflected so what conditions needs to be met for bullet so it won't be reflected?

Comment: I mean is it possible to fire a bullet so it will move along with rock (not through it) and not reflect from it?